# win32-process frozen string on CreateProcess?

Tags: ruby, windows, win32-process

I tried using Process.create to start a sub process to execute a batch file in a particular directory. This is what I did:

```
proc_info = Process.create(  
:app_name => ENV['SystemRoot'] + "\\system32\\cmd.exe",  
:command_line => "C:\\some_bin\\some_cmd.bat some_parameter",  
:cwd => "C:\\some_workspace")
```

The execution failed as:

```
(eval):3:in 'call': can't modify frozen string (TypeError)  
from (eval):3:in 'CreateProcess'  
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/win32-process-0.6.5/lib/win32/pro
cess.rb:873:in 'create'  
from some_process_script.rb:11
```

Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an unfrozen copy of a frozen string using `dup`.

Do you happen to know where the RDoc for Win32 Process is?

Comment: I actually tried to 'hack' the process.rb and change the problematic line from `hash['app_name']` to `hash['app_name'].dup`.  But still, the same error message was returned

Comment: Can you post in the question the hack you attempted, with surrounding code?

Comment: @svnpenn The first sentence was intended as an answer, and the second sentence a request to make the question more informative. If I didn't have the first sentence, it would have been more suitable as a comment.